# Confirm that this logger configuration is safe

Tags: sonarqube

When I use Sonarqube to scan my code, I get a Security Hotspot issue (Make sure that this logger's configuration is safe) for the following line:

`serviceCollection.AddSingleton(new LoggerFactory().AddLambdaLogger(loggerOptions));`

How would I resolve this issue?

Comment: You may want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182098/sonar-issue-make-sure-that-this-loggers-configuration-is-safe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sonar issue: Make sure that this logger's configuration is safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182098/sonar-issue-make-sure-that-this-loggers-configuration-is-safe)